# Variable in a closure to avoid multiple if's

Tags: grails, closures, grails-orm

I need a better solution for the following code block, that better meets the DRY principle. Is there a means to handle the operators <,...,>= in each closure as a variable ?

```
def query
    if (wvOp == ' ')
        query = Notiz.where {
        notiztext =~ "${params['notiztext']}" &&
        referenz =~ "${params['referenz']}" 
    }
    if (wvOp == '<')
        query = Notiz.where {
        notiztext =~ "${params['notiztext']}" && 
        referenz =~ "${params['referenz']}" &&
        anlagetermin < wiedervorlage
    }
    if (wvOp == '<=')
        query = Notiz.where {
        notiztext =~ "${params['notiztext']}" &&
        referenz =~ "${params['referenz']}" &&
        anlagetermin <= wiedervorlage
    }
    if (wvOp == '=')
        query = Notiz.where {
        notiztext =~ "${params['notiztext']}" &&
        referenz =~ "${params['referenz']}" &&
        anlagetermin == wiedervorlage
    }
    if (wvOp == '>')
        query = Notiz.where {
        notiztext =~ "${params['notiztext']}" &&
        referenz =~ "${params['referenz']}" &&
        anlagetermin > wiedervorlage
    }
    if (wvOp == '>=')
        query = Notiz.where {
        notiztext =~ "${params['notiztext']}" &&
        referenz =~ "${params['referenz']}" &&
        anlagetermin >= wiedervorlage
    }
    query.findAll()
```

peter
Dortmund, Germany

Comment: If you are willing to give up the benefits of a `where` query (type safety, compile time checks, `DetachedCriteria`, etc...) then the suggestion below about using a criteria query can work.  If you want the benefits that the `where` query has to offer then you can get rid of all of the duplication as shown in my answer below, but you can't get rid of the individual boolean expressions.  That is the nature of how `where` queries are processed.  The structure of the criteria has to be knowable at compile time, unlike criteria queries. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to replace your `where` with a criteria-based query. Somthing along these lines:

```
// translate incoming comparison operator to equivalent criteria method
def opMap = [ '<': 'lt', '<=': 'lte', '=': 'eq', '>': 'gt', '>=': 'gte' ]

def c = Notiz.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
    and {
        ilike(notiztext, params['notiztext'])
        ilike(referenz, params['referenz'])
        if (wvOp in opMap.keySet()) {
           "${opMap[wvOp]}"(anlagetermin, wiedervorlage)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that the `and` block there is superfluous.  The default behavior is to `and` together all of the criteria.

Comment: I used the criteria approach, ommitting the and block.that's what my solution now looks like:    def c = Notiz.createCriteria()
  c.list {
   if (anlOp in opMap.keySet())
    "${opMap[anlOp]}"("anlagetermin", anlage)
   ilike("notiztext", params.notiztext)
   ilike("referenz", params.referenz)
   if (wvOp in opMap.keySet())
    "${opMap[wvOp]}"("wiedervorlagetermin", wiedervorlage)
  }  the atvantage is, that I could easily add a second criterion with an operator

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate a bunch of the duplication.  Instead of this...

```
def query

if (wvOp == ' ')
    query = Notiz.where {
        notiztext =~ "${params['notiztext']}" &&
        referenz =~ "${params['referenz']}" 
    }
}
if (wvOp == '<')
    query = Notiz.where {
        notiztext =~ "${params['notiztext']}" && 
        referenz =~ "${params['referenz']}" &&
        anlagetermin < wiedervorlage
    }
}
if (wvOp == '<=')
    query = Notiz.where {
        notiztext =~ "${params['notiztext']}" &&
        referenz =~ "${params['referenz']}" &&
        anlagetermin <= wiedervorlage
    }
}
if (wvOp == '=')
    query = Notiz.where {
        notiztext =~ "${params['notiztext']}" &&
        referenz =~ "${params['referenz']}" &&
        anlagetermin == wiedervorlage
    }
}
if (wvOp == '>')
    query = Notiz.where {
        notiztext =~ "${params['notiztext']}" &&
        referenz =~ "${params['referenz']}" &&
        anlagetermin > wiedervorlage
    }
}
if (wvOp == '>=')
    query = Notiz.where {
        notiztext =~ "${params['notiztext']}" &&
        referenz =~ "${params['referenz']}" &&
        anlagetermin >= wiedervorlage
    }
}
```

You could do something like this...

```
def query = Notiz.where {

    notiztext =~ "${params['notiztext']}" &&
    referenz =~ "${params['referenz']}" 

    if (wvOp == '<') {
        anlagetermin < wiedervorlage
    } else if (wvOp == '<=')
        anlagetermin <= wiedervorlage
    } else if (wvOp == '=')
        anlagetermin == wiedervorlage
    } else if (wvOp == '>')
        anlagetermin > wiedervorlage
    } else if (wvOp == '>=')
        anlagetermin >= wiedervorlage
    }
}
```